# Where JCombBox items should be declared on a MVC pattern?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jcombobox

I know it's a rather noob question but it's bugging me since i've found myself with the situation.

I have created an object with a MVC pattern. I have a view with a JComboBox. The items on this JComboBox represent the state of the object (pending, work in progress, ready) that will be stored in the model.

My question is, should these values be inserted directly in the View when the JComboBox is declared or should i have them as an ArrayList in the model and then loaded in the JComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is: which component should have the knowledge about the acceptable values for the object's state?

And then, to me the only answer can be: the model. And this knowledge shouldn't be spread and duplicated over many different places, so the view should ask the model for the list of possible state values and prepare the combo box from the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. It clarifies a lot of things.